# Retrieve mails and process each attachment individually

Tags: shell-script, command-line, email

I want to retrieve new mails using a shell script and if the mail I just retrieved has attachments, these attachments should be saved to a folder. Before the next mail is retrieved, the attachments should be processed individually, e.g. the name should be checked and the file should be moved etc.

I know how to retrieve mails from the command line and save the attachments (with mutt), but then all mail attachments are saved. So I cannot check and process the attachments for each mail immediately after receiving it.

I would be glad about tips.

cu
Andy

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a script below. Please note that I'm not a programmer. But I believe this could be a good start for You.

Run it for each message like this `./script FILENAME`

There are couple of things to finish:

- duplicate filenames,
- missing filenames,
- Better handling of multipart/related.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import email

fp = open(sys.argv[1],"r")
msg = email.message_from_file(fp)
fp.close()

content_types_to_skip=[
  'text/plain',
  'text/html',
  'multipart/mixed',
  'multipart/alternative',
  'multipart/related'
]
attach_dir='/tmp/attachments/'
if not os.path.exists(attach_dir):
  os.mkdir(attach_dir)

# get text/plain only
if msg.is_multipart():
  for part in msg.walk():
    ctype = part.get_content_type()

    if ctype not in content_types_to_skip:
      attachment = part.get_payload(decode=True)
      name = str(part.get_filename())
      fp = open(attach_dir + name,"wb")
      fp.write(attachment)
      fp.close()
```

Comment: Cool start. Thank you, Jakub!